# How to change pop up message for in app purchase?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have added in app purchase in my app.Now i have difrent plans for that.So the popup which appears it shows a wrong value.As your have bought just bought 20 connections but it shows 75 connections.[image]

I have plan id has `com.prefix.75chats`.Now i am not able to change this.Please tell how can i fix it ?

Comment: can you share some code please?

Comment: what code i show ?

Comment: the one where user clicks on inApp purchase and what you offer him to purchase

Comment: The description comes from your in--app product that you set up in iTunesConnect.

Comment: Which things i need to update ?

Comment: The text description of your in-app purchase product in iTunesConnect.apple.com.

Comment: I have added text in description on app store but it is not same text as displayed in popup

Answer (score 0):

The messages are coming from the App Store, so that you can not change the the massage

Comment: I want to change value of 75 to 20.In product id i have passed com.prefix.75chats ?